# Filter by COUNT(*) > 1 and display all relevant rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table Asset (see below). For all Asset_Type that are not "Automobile" I need to display it and round the Asset_Value to the nearest hundreds. I need to **omit Asset_Type type with only one asset** and sequence the results by asset type.

```
+-------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+
|    Asset_Type     |        Asset_Description         |  Asset_Value  |
+-------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+
| Automobile        | Model T                          | $100,923.99   |
| Automobile        | 1967 Ford Mustang Convertible    | $60,000.00    |
| Automobile        | 1975 MGB                         | $52,000.00    |
| Automobile        | 1962 Avanti                      | $88,000.00    |
| Wine              | 2000 LaGrange Cabernet Sauvignon | $235.25       |
| Wine              | 1999 LaGrange Cabernet Sauvignon | $400.88       |
| Fine Art          | Hula-Hoop Girl Painting          | $1,000.00     |
| Antique Furniture | 1860 Setee                       | $1,200.00     |
| Antique Furniture | 1860 4-Post Bed                  | $1,450.00     |
| Antique Furniture | Art Deco Dresser                 | $869.99       |
| Antique Furniture | 1830 Empire Chairs (4)           | $2,200.00     |
| Structure         | Historic Register Barn           | $335,000.00   |
| Structure         | Historic Register Silo           | $335,000.00   |
| Fine Art          | The Thinker                      | $1,200,000.00 |
| Fine Art          | The Scream                       | $3,350,000.00 |
| Coins             | 1880 2-Headed Penny              | $500.00       |
| Coins             | 1932 A-Series Dime               | $750.00       |
| Coins             | Buffalo Nickel                   | $469.99       |
| Stamps            | Moon Landing                     | $175.00       |
| Stamps            | American Centennial              | $3,000.50     |
| Commodities       | 175 Acre Cotton Field            | $750,500.00   |
| Memorabilia       | UofF Football Trophy             | $16,555.55    |
| Memorabilia       | UofF Football Jersey             | $16,555.55    |
+-------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+
```

I'm able to get most criteria except omitting asset with only ONE count.

```
SELECT Asset_Type, ROUND(Asset_Value/100, 0)*100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM Asset
WHERE Asset_Type <> "Automobile"
ORDER BY Asset_Type;
```

I've tried using `GROUP BY Asset_Type, Asset_Value HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, but that results in 2 rows with matching asset type and value. Since I need to still list all asset type, GROUP BY will not list all rows.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Asset_Type,
       Round(Asset_Value / 100, 0) * 100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM   Asset
WHERE  Asset_Type IN (SELECT Asset_Type
                      FROM   Asset
                      WHERE  Asset_Type <> 'Automobile'
                      GROUP  BY Asset_Type
                      HAVING Count(*) > 1)
ORDER  BY Asset_Type
```

Or use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT Asset_Type,
       Round(Asset_Value / 100, 0) * 100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM   #test t
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT Asset_Type
               FROM   #test f
               WHERE  Asset_Type <> 'Automobile'
                      AND f.Asset_Type = t.Asset_Type
               GROUP  BY Asset_Type
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
ORDER  BY Asset_Type
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it! The subquery makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Shep's answer using joins instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT a1.Asset_Type, ROUND(a1.Asset_Value/100, 0)*100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM Asset a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Asset_Type, COUNT(*) AS frequency
    FROM Asset
    GROUP BY Asset_Type
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) a2
ON a1.Asset_Type = a2.Asset_Type
WHERE a1.Asset_Type <> "Automobile"
ORDER BY a1.Asset_Type;
```

Comment: Asset_Type <> 'Automobile'

Comment: Thanks buddy...updating it now :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.  If I am correctly understanding the goal, the following should work:

```
SELECT a.Asset_Type,
       Round(a.Asset_Value / 100, 0) * 100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM   Asset a
       JOIN (SELECT Asset_Type
             FROM   Asset
             GROUP  BY Asset_Type
             HAVING Count(1) > 1) types
         ON types.Asset_Type = a.Asset_Type
WHERE  a.Asset_Type <> "Automobile"
ORDER  BY Asset_Type
```

In a derived table you get a list of all the distinct Asset Types that have multiple rows, then you join to that from the original query so that you are essentially filtering on only the types that have multiple rows.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was posting from my phone, and it was giving me some sort of error so it took a few tries before I successfully submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Asset_Type, ROUND(Asset_Value/100, 0)*100 AS [Rounded Asset Value]
FROM Asset
WHERE Asset_Type <> "Automobile"
and Asset_Type not in 
    (select Asset_Type, count(*) 
    from Asset
    group by Asset_Type
    having count(*) =1)
ORDER BY Asset_Type;
```

Comment: Thank you Shep, I tried this but it seems like I need to use EXISTS with this query's FROM clause. I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: @holdmyunicorn - Problem is two column's selected `Asset_Type, count(*)` in `sub-query` which is not allowed when you are not using `EXISTS` . Check my answer for exists